# java - sorting the list of employee names using collections

Tags: java, list, collections

I think this may be a duplicate question. But couldn't find the answer for my requirement.

I have a list of names (String) such as

```
Merill, Gopi, kamal, orange, white
```

I need to do something to get the list in ascending order using collections like the following

```
Gopi, kamal, Merill, orange, white
```

Is it possible to get the list in alphabeticalorder?

Can anyone please tell how to sort this using collections?

(Please provide a solution before closing this questiona as duplicate)

Comment: If it is closed as duplicate, you can find your answer in the duplicated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know your trying to sort it using Collections, but here's a simple way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    String[] values = new String[] {"Some item", "another item", "1 last more", "nevermind", "this is different"};
    System.out.println("Before: " + Arrays.toString(values));
    Arrays.sort(values, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String arg0, String arg1) {
            return arg0.compareTo(arg1);
        }
    });
    System.out.println("After: " + Arrays.toString(values));
}
```

And this is outputted:

> Before: [Some item, another item, 1 last more, nevermind, this is different]
>
> After: [1 last more, Some item, another item, nevermind, this is different]

The array is sorted numerical/other first, then capital-alphabetical, then lowercase-alphabetical

Comment: Hi Alex, Is it possible to sort in an alphabetical order (a,b,c,d...)?

Answer (score 5):

You can use this:

```
Collections.sort(list, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)
```

[`String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER) is a `Comparator<String>` in `String` class. Note that this is not locale-aware.

Answer (score 3):

You've already mentioned the solution in your post:

> Can anyone please tell how to sort this using collectins?

Use `java.util.Collections.sort(...)`.

[The API for Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html).

Answer (score 1):

**Collections.sort(pass the list)** will soft in ascending order. If you want to sort your own way then you need to use **Comparator** but here there is no need of doing that.